# How to check the existence of a key in params in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm still trying to make my second feed work but it doesn't quite work at the moment.

I struggled with this error and i'm wondering what i'm doing wrong so if someone could explain me that would be pretty good.

users_controller.rb:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
  @microposts_second = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page] + 1)
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<% if @user.microposts.any? %>
  <h3>Microposts (<%= @user.microposts.count %>)</h3>
  <ol class="microposts">
    <%= render @microposts_second %>
  </ol>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

That's what giving me the error when I viewed it:

> undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

Comment: `params[:page] + 1` - this seems to be the error line. This should be `params[:page].to_i + 1` but what is value of `params[:page]` ? It looks like nil!

Comment: Ahh oke I see well at least the error was solved thanks alot @dp7. But it's still showing the same feed page so I need to figure out that part why it isn't showing the second page of the feed.

Comment: Can you add your logs to question when you click to see the second feed ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not rely on `params[:page]`, you need to make sure that the value exists. Moreover, since you are trying to add an integer, you also need to make sure that the type matches.

```
if params.has_key?(:page)
  current_page_count = params[:page].to_i
end
```

So you can use the method: `has_key?` to ensure that the value of `:page` exists in `params`.

Comment: @N.Oraile If the answer helped you, you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is raised when you try to add `params[:page]`. If there is no page parameter passed in the URL, then this error will be raised. Try this to skip the error

```
def somedef
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    pageno = params[:page].present? ? params[:page].to_i + 1 : nil
    @microposts_second = @user.microposts.paginate(page: pageno)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Often I need to check presence of

```
params {"shoes" => {"number" => "11"}}
```

when I don't know if hash "shoes" exists (maybe was created dinamically !).
If I try to call params[:shoes][:number] where params[:shoes] is nil I'll trigger an undefined exception.

Using **rescue** I can check directly params[:shoes][:number] without trigger an exception.

```
if(params[:shoes][:number] rescue false)
  # here you can safe reading params[:shoes][:number]
  # managing exception if params[:shoes] (or [:shoes][:number]) is nil
end
```

I hope this helpful